# How to include multiple fonts into single text

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an Arabic text in a pdf file. When I copy the text into Text Widget it becomes weird characters. When I checked the pdf file properties I found that it uses HQPB1, HQPB2, HQPB3, HQPB4 fonts, so I imported all of these fonts to my pubsec.yaml file. The problem is that I can use only one of these 4 fonts at a time but the pdf file uses all of these 4 fonts simultaneously.

[this is the original text from pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaKMp.png)

[when I added  HQPB1.ttf only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPfO5.png)

[when I added HQPB2.ttf only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiUuG.png)

So I want to include all of these 4 fonts in a Text so that each individual font should be used when it is needed as pdf does.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'Hello ', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Serif", fontSize: 30, color: Colors.black)),
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 30)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Roboto", fontSize: 30, color: Colors.red)),
    ],
  ),
)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I take large portion of text in database and keep it in the variable like. It will be very uncomfortable to use textspan in this case. I could not find any solution to my problem that's why I am now using PDFView instead.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have multiple styles on one Text widget you have to use `RichText`. `RichText` has a `children[]` so you can have custom `TextStyle` (which will use whatever font you want) for each `TextSpan`

Check it out here -> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html

Comment: correct, well I hope it was clear anyway, easily seen in the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Text.rich(
      TextSpan(
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
            text: 'Hello ',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Serif",
              fontSize: 30,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: 'bold',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Arial",
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.blue,
              fontSize: 30,
            ),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: ' world!',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Roboto",
              fontSize: 30,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```